# Backdoor:PHP/webshell Malware

Tags: php, wordpress, security, malware

I have this website which i want to replace because its outdated, we made a new website. But as always before uploading the new website to the live environment i make a backup of the current live website. While i was downloading the Wordpress installation my windows defender popped up with the following message. Malware found:

> Backdoor:PHP/webshell

What exactly is this? Is it dangerous for my computer or is it a backdoor for the website. How did this happen. Anything would be really helpful on this matter. Should i run a scan on my whole computer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your site has been hacked, I wouldn't use anything from the old website.

Comment: A webshell is generally a script that'll mirror your file manager, it'll also have custom tools built into it so that the attacker can upload files and/or change permissions (you'll find this is a common method of how phishing happens) because the attacker has found a vulnerability within your site.

Comment: @Pedro, maybe i should've just said that too instead of my long winded approach xD

Comment: @PedroLobito Is this also a risk for my computer itself ? or just the website?

Comment: You need to ask yourself how this happened? How did they get into the server to inject this? SQL Inject? Do you have a RAT on your machine? Or perhaps there is a vulnerability on your website? I would change user names and passwords and do a FULL scan on your PC. You can also do scans on your web server but if you can. A rebuild would be best and quicker! (Thats if you have that option of course) - Accept my answer if it helps. Good luck.

Comment: @irishwill200, it's wordpress.. The most hacked platform ever LOL

Comment: @Kevin.a No, I don't think so.

Comment: I suppose another reason is if you are using a cracked source? Full of nasty creatures ^.^ @Option Yeah i only realized wordpress was mentioned. Your right there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Backdoor:PHP/WebShell.A drops following files***:

```
<root folder>/tmp/bp.pl - used to listen for shell commands
<root folder>/tmp/bc.pl - used to send shell commands
```

**Sends email**

Backdoor:PHP/WebShell.A sends an email that contains your IP address and reportsits installation to the Yahoo! account "freedom20900".

**Allows backdoor access and control**

Backdoor:PHP/WebShell.A can give a malicious hackers access to perform the following actions:

```
Archive or extract files
Brute-force logins for FTP, MySQL, pgsql
Create or delete folders
Download files
Encode or decode files
Open a bash shell command, which allows the remote attacker to execute remote commands
Open files
Rename files
Run SQL commands
Search folders
Show active connections
Show computers the infected computer had access to
Show running services
Show user accounts
Show IP configuration
```

**Connects to certain servers**

Backdoor:PHP/WebShell.A connects to the following servers for the purpose of receiving arbitrary information, sent by a malicious hacker, about your PC:

```
crackfor.me
hashcracking.info
hashcracking.ru
md5.rednoize.com
www.hashcrack.com
www.md5decrypter.com
www.milw0rm.com
```

**In normal terms**

Your site has been hacked and perhaps been manipulated in a way that will be a risk if you try to use it. Do not use this source and remove / delete from your machine. I would suggest doing a major browse / scan for any more potential viruses and change your user information such as passwords and emails on the server (Since they may know these by now).

Reference: https://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/threat/encyclopedia/entry.aspx?Name=Backdoor:PHP/WebShell.A